# Micronaut Framework / Logged in but unauthorized

Tags: micronaut

I am encountering a problem in my micronaut app.
If I want to visit '/index', I have to login.
When I'am logged in the '/index' page is correctly displayed.
At this very moment if I want to visit the '/periods/list/my' I'am redirirect to 
the 'unauthorized-target-url'

The strangest thing is that visiting '/index' is still ok...
Could this be a security configuration problem ?

HomeController.java

```
@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
@Controller("/")
public class HomeController {
    @Get("/")
    @View("index")
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_AUTHENTICATED)
    Map<String, Object> index(@Nullable Principal principal) {
       ...
    }
}
```

PeriodController.java

```
@Controller("/periods")
@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
public class PeriodController {
    @Get("/list/my")
    @View("periods/my")
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_AUTHENTICATED)
    Map<String, Object> myPeriods(@Nullable Principal principal) {
        ...
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
micronaut:
    application:
        name: ws
    security:
        enabled: true
        endpoints:
            login:
                enabled: true 
            logout:
                enabled: true
                path: '/logout'
        interceptUrlMap:
            -
                pattern: /public/**
                httpMethod: GET
                access:
                    - isAnonymous()
        session:
            enabled: true 
            login-success-target-url: '/'
            login-failure-target-url: '/login/authFailed'
            logout-target-url: '/'
            unauthorized-target-url: '/unauthorized'
            forbidden-target-url: '/forbidden'
    session:
        http:
            cookie: true
            header: false
```

logs

```
11:47:20.134 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] DEBUG i.m.h.server.netty.NettyHttpServer - Server localhost:8080 Received Request: GET /periods/list/my
11:47:20.134 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Matching route GET - /periods/list/my
11:47:20.134 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Matched route GET - /periods/list/my to controller class com.gvhr.controllers.PeriodController
11:47:20.135 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header
11:47:20.135 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG i.m.s.t.TokenAuthenticationFetcher - Unauthenticated request GET, /periods/list/my, no token found.
11:47:20.135 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Failure to authenticate request. GET /periods/list/my.
11:47:20.135 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Unauthorized request GET /periods/list/my. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule rejected the request.
11:47:20.149 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] DEBUG i.m.h.server.netty.NettyHttpServer - Server localhost:8080 Received Request: GET /unauthorized
11:47:20.149 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Matching route GET - /unauthorized
11:47:20.149 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Matched route GET - /unauthorized to controller class com.gvhr.controllers.HomeController
```

Comment: @sergio-del-amo, I do not know why your comment is gone, but here is the link to the project that reproduces the strange behavior https://github.com/ziguane/sample2 thank in advance

Comment: Any solution for this yet ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is root cause of your problem, but I had similar symptoms.  The cookie use was unpredictable.  Sometimes, the cookie would work on a path and then fail on another path.  Very random.

I found the problem: Each page/path sent back a cookie with a different path.  This means the pages '/' and '/test' each had a cookie.  When you re-visited the pages, the browser would send one cookie for page '/', but two cookies for '/test'.

The fix, in your *application.yml*, make sure the *cookiePath* is set:

```
micronaut:
  session:
    http:
      cookiePath: /
```

This forces just one SESSION cookie for the whole server.

I will probably update this when I log a change request.

I also replaced (@Replaces) two Micronaut beans: SessionSecurityfilterRejectionHandler and SessionLoginHandler to support automatic re-direction to the original page after login.

I get the feeling that Micronaut is not yet focused on the HTML/User interaction yet :).

Comment: Hi Mike ! Thanks for your answer. I have the same feeling. Would you agree to share your two beans please ? Setting the cookiePath do not fix my problem, unfortunately.

Comment: I added the code to a blog post.  I hope it helps.  It did not really solve the problem, but the core classes helped me understand what was going on.  I spent a lot of time in debugger looking at that code.  [blog](http://michaelphouston.blogspot.com/2018/11/micronaut-and-redirect-on-security.html)

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I will have a look. Do you use this framework in production ?

Comment: "I get the feeling that Micronaut is not yet focused on the HTML/User interaction yet :)." Micronauts main focus is for microservices that typically interact with other servers, however time and effort has been put forward to support HTML views and cookie based authentication. @FabriceV If the cookie path did not resolve the issue, please file an issue on github so it can be fixed.

Comment: @JamesKleeh I made this clarification in the issue #882 https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/882 Thanks for your help

Comment: @JamesKleeh, I did not mean to minimize the HTML/User interaction work in Micronaut :).  I really like it and it is in great shape.  I just meant that it is early its life.  I am making a cautious jump from Grails to Micronaut. I wanted others to know they should not expect every option that Grails supports.

Comment: @FabriceV, I do not use micronaut in production.  Probably a long way off for me.

Comment: BTW, I switched over to JWT-Cookies.  This avoids the cookie path issue.  They are more persistent and fit better with the REST world.  I still have to find out how to use JWT-Bearer and Cookie mode at the same time (not sure if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Issue fixed in Micronaut version 1.1.1